# How to add tags to blogspot posts without editing them?

Tags: tags, blogs, blogger, blogspot

In one of my `blogspot` blog, I have written 25 posts with tag "`XYZ`". Now I want to attach one more tag "`PQR`" to those posts. I don't want to edit each and every post to add the new tag. How can I achieve my task in a shorter way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Sign in to blogger

2.Click in you blog name

3.Click on posts

4.On the Top right corner,to the left of the search bar,you would see a drop down box written as "all labels".Click it and select "xyz

5.Now Check each post.(the checkbox is to the left of the title of post)

6 Immeditialy at the top,to the left of publish button,there would be drop down box...click on new label and type "pqr".Thats it

[image]